# How can I use instance data in form validation in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make sure a list name is unique for a certain user. Here is my view:

```
    list = List(user=user)
    new_list_form = ListForm(request.POST, instance=list)
    if new_list_form.is_valid():
        new_list_form.save()
```

And here is the validator that cleans the title (the name of the list):

```
    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if List.objects.get(user=user, title=title):
            raise forms.ValidationError("List title must be unique.")
        return title
```

Which doesn't work because `'ListForm' object has no attribute 'user'`

How can I access the user variable given by "instance=list" from the clean_title function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object passed to `ModelForm(instance=)` is stored in `ModelForm().instance`.  Try

```
    if List.objects.get(user=self.instance.user, title=title):
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the [unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) attribute of the Meta class of your model:

```
class List(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "title"),)
```

Then your form will fail validation if a user attempts to reuse a title.